# Show only day and month in input with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I need to show only the day and the month within the input, I already got out, but within not handle just get the full date.

```
<input type="date" ng-model="someDate">
<p>{{someDate | date:'dd MMMM'}}</p>
```

in my controller

```
mainAppControllers.controller('DoarScanCtrl', ['myservice','$rootScope','$scope', '$routeParams', '$location','$timeout','$filter',
function(myservice, $rootScope, $scope, $routeParams, $location,$timeout ,$filter){

$scope.someDate = new Date();
```

Comment: It looks like to me that you'll need to find a custom widget that only displays the day and month.

Comment: day/month is not a date. So you can't use input type `"date"`. This is a custom input type you have to do on your own.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/22392328/how-to-format-date-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `watch` model value and update it upon change.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$timeout) {
  $scope.dateObj = new Date();
  $scope.$watch('someDate', function() {
       var month = $scope.dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
       var day = $scope.dateObj.getUTCDate();
       $scope.someDate = month + "/" + day;
  });
})
```

and in your template

```
<input ng-model='someDate' ng-trim='false'/>
        <p>{{someDate}}</p>
```

**[See my  Working Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nisham/mgPGS/110/)**

Comment: Interesting solution, but on your jsfiddle input doesn't allow to change the value.